Add a custom column to admin users list displaying custom user metadata
I have added a custom meta field to users called "customer_code".  This all works and stores the information just fine.
I have added the "Customer Code" column to the users admin page like so:
add_filter('manage_users_columns', 'db_add_customer_code_column');
function db_add_customer_code_column($columns) {
    $columns = array_merge(array('customer_code' => 'Customer Code'), $columns);
    return $columns;
}

Again, this works just fine and the column appears on the users admin page.
However, I then have this code to populate the column with the "customer_code" meta data:
add_action('manage_users_custom_column',  'db_show_customer_code_column_content', 10, 3);
function db_show_customer_code_column_content($value, $column_name, $user_id) {
    $user = get_userdata( $user_id );
    if ('customer_code' == $column_name){
        $customer_code = get_the_author_meta( 'customer_code', $user_id );
        return $customer_code;
        return $value;
    }
}

The column, however, remains completely blank!
I have used this exact same code on another site and it works perfectly there.  It's also definitely getting the customer code too because if I use "echo $customer_code" (instead of "return") then it correctly spits out all the customer codes across the top of the page;  it just seems to be refusing to return each of them into the column for some reason!
Any ideas???

Just a quick follow on from this;  Just as a test I've also just tried:
return ("I'm a little teapot!");
Still nothing!  It just seems to be completely ignoring the "return" command altogether.  There's no errors or anything appearing in the console window either.

There are some mistakes in your code. From the available user ID, you should better use WordPress get_user_meta function than get_the_author_meta function, to get and display custom user metadata.
Also note that manage_users_custom_column is a filter hook, that requires to return the main argument $output at the end, inside the related hooked function.
Try the following instead:
add_filter('manage_users_columns', 'db_add_customer_code_column');
function db_add_customer_code_column($columns) {
    return array_merge( array('customer_code' => esc_html__('Customer Code') ), $columns );
}


add_filter('manage_users_custom_column',  'db_show_customer_code_column_content', 10, 3);
function db_show_customer_code_column_content( $output, $column_name, $user_id) {
    if ( 'customer_code' === $column_name ){
        $output = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'customer_code', true );
    }
    return $output;
}

It should work.
If I replace:
$output = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'customer_code', true );

with:
$output = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'first_name', true );

I get something like:

So as you can see the column is populated, with the user's first name. Be sure that customer_code is the right meta_key to be used, checking in wp_usermeta database table.

I have copy/pasted your code in exactly, but the column is still completely blank (I have also cleared my browser cache).
It's definitely getting the right customer code from "get_user_meta" though because again, if I change "return" to "echo", it spits all the customer codes out at the top of the screen.
It's making absolutely no sense to me at all as to why this isn't working!  It absolutely should!

@GraphicDetail Sorry but never use echo in a filter hook, always return the main function argument (here it's $output). I have added to my answer some explanations and a screenshot (please take a look).

Oh yes, I totally realise that "echo" isn't the code to use here;  I was merely using that to test that it was actually getting the correct data.  For some obscure reason though, it just doesn't want to return it.  :-/  In fact, it won't return ANYTHING at all.  i.e., "return 'Hello World!';" doesn't work!  It should just populate every field in the column with "Hello World!", but it's still blank!  (And yes, "customer_code" is definitely the correct meta_key.

It looks like there was a conflict because something else (perhaps in the theme) is also calling the "manage_users_custom_column" filter.
Increasing my call's priority has fixed the issue (changed "10" to "15"):
add_filter('manage_users_custom_column',  'db_show_customer_code_column_content', 15, 3);


This should not be an answer, but an edit at the end of your question (as nobody can guess by magic that something else is using manage_users_custom_column hook)… I remember you that in your question, the function db_show_customer_code_column_content code is not correct and can't work as it is.
